# Angular http request with json param

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

In my RESTful api one of the resources exposes a GET method that accept json as a parameter named 'query'. This parameter is passed directly to the MongoDB query allowing users to query the database directly using mongo syntax.

The problem I'm having is that the request always looks like this:

```
?&query=%7B%22source%22:%22incident%22%7D
```

Where it should look something like this:

```
?&query={'source': 'incident'}
```

This is how I am sending the GET request:

```
var query = {};
if ($scope.sourceFilter) { query.source = $scope.sourceFilter; }
    var query = JSON.stringify(query);
    $http.get('/api/feedbackEntries', {params: {limit: $scope.limit, query: query}}).success(function(data) { .......
```

I am doing the same thing on other get requests and I don't get this issue.

Am I doing something wrong here ? Is this to do with the way angular parses params ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I figured this one out. Looking at the request I was making:

```
$http.get('/api/feedbackEntries',
```

I saw that the url does not end with a trailing slash. This was the only difference I could see compared with other requests that were working fine. So I added the trailing slash and magically it works. I can't explain why, whether it's something within angular or elsewhere .. but this is how I fixed the problem.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: What bothers me here is that if you would have used ngResource, that would have taken care of your trailing slashes! So my votedown is pretty much very evil.

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry that I assumed that, and thanks for the up vote.

Answer (score 2):

Like the `$http` [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) say

> **params** – `{Object.<string|Object>}` – Map of strings or objects which will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. **If the value is not a string, it will be JSONified.**

Latter emphasis is added by me.

So the `query` property of the object you pass to the `params` configuration option is an Object. This means is will be JSONified, which means the same as

```
JSON.stringify(query);
```

So this

```
{'source': 'incident'}
```

Turns to this:

```
'{"source": "incident"}'
```

As [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) states:

> ... only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

As it happens `{`, `}` and `"` are not on that list and have to be url encoded to be used in a url. In your case `%7B` corresponds to `{`, `%7D` corresponds to `}` and `%22` corresponds to `"`.

So what is happening is normal and most server software automatically decodes the url query parameters for you, so they will be presented normally. Most likely you'll need to parse it back to JSON somehow!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jake. Are you saying I shouldn't be adding parameters to GET requests ? I can't see how this goes against what HTTP GET requests are meant for .. maybe I have misunderstood. I don't think I should use POST here as I am not creating anything, I'm simply GETting data from the database based on the query provided.

Comment: Nope, i misread your question, I'll edit to answer your question

Comment: Cheers Jake. This is helpful. Still a bit confused about why this is only happening on this request. I'll keep digging though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using RESTFul apis concider using [ngResource](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-resource.js), [ngResource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)

Include it in your module:

```
yourApp = angular.module('yourApp', ['ngResource'])
```

Add your service:

```
yourApp.factory('YourService', ['$resource', function($resource){
return $resource('link/to/your/object', {});
}]);
```

Add your controller

```
yourApp.controller('YourController', [$scope, 
'YourService', function($scope, YourService) {

$scope.yourData = YourService.get(); 
$scope.yourData = YourService.query(); //(When obtaining arrays from JSON.)
```

I've found this is the best way using a RESTFull api.

Comment: unfortunately for reasons that are out of my control i'm unable to use ngResource and I am stuck with $http for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I used to get search result from my server, it works for me sending POST request with JSON params without .

```
var service = {
  getResult: function ({"username": "roman", "gender": "male"}) {

    var promise = $http({
      url: ServerManager.getServerUrl(),
      method: "POST",
      data: params,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('getResult success.');
      return data;

    }).error(function (data, status) {
      console.log('getResult error.');
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
return service;
```