# (Angular JS) How filter $http.get by passing params if the response is an array of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am making an `$http GET` request to my REST api to get a list of projects. What I want to do is filter the response using the `param` option to only get projects assigned to a particular person.

```
var config = {
  withCredentials: true,
  params: {
    AssigneeId: 12423
  }
};
$http.get(baseUrl + 'projects', config).then(function successCallback(response) {
  //do things on success
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  //do things on error
});
```

The `AssigneeId` field is a property of the `project` object. The issue I am having is that the response for the `$http.get` is an array of `JSON` objects rendering the `param` useless. My response looks something like this:

```
[{
  ProjectName: 'project 1',
  AssigneeId: 12311,
  size: 5
}, {
  ProjectName: 'project 2',
  AssigneeId: 15232,
  size: 4
}, {
  ProjectName: 'project 3',
  AssigneeId: 43123,
  size: 2
}, {
  ProjectName: 'project 4',
  AssigneeId: 12423,
  size: 6
}]
```

What I wanted to do with the `param` was to only get `'project 4'` as a response to my `GET` request. I think it is not working due to to the response being an array? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to filter it with params, the server has to support that...

Comment: you are asking for the api server to give you a filtered list, for this to hanpend you must have an API route that takes parameters something like /getProjectsById/{id} and have it filter the results for you. Also take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753072/angular-http-request-with-json-param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kevin B has mentioned it has to be supported by your server. You need to talk to your service guys to fix this or pass the right params. Till your server guy fixes this. You can have this new code

```
var assigneeId = 12423;
var config = {
  withCredentials: true
};
$http.get(baseUrl + 'projects', config )
 .then( successCallback(response){
   var assignedProject = response.filter(function(o){
     return o.AssigneeId === assigneeId; 
   }).map(function(o){
     return o.ProjectName;
   })[0];
 }, errorCallback(response){
    //do things on error
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely will let the service guys know.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing You just copied my answer.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171, When I was adding my answer I only noticed the filter function. I did not see the map function.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it when you get response.

```
response = response.filter(function(a) {
  return a.AssigneeId === config.params.AssigneeId;
}).map(function(a) {
  return a.ProjectName;
})[0];
```